# Shutdown Thread Pool obtained from Executors.newFixedThreadPool

Tags: java, android

I am using Executors.newFixedThreadPool  to start a thread every two minutes and the thread sends data to server.

After sometime there will not be any data to be sent. In this case how do I shutdown the pool.
Can I initiate the shutdown of the pool from the same thread which is run through ThreadPool

Code is :

scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

```
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @SuppressLint("ShowToast")

            public void run() {

                Log.e("Thread Pool -1 is running", "ThreadPool-1");
                sendDataToServer();


            }

        };

        scheduledThreadPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, INITIAL_DELAY,
                DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        }
```

Comment: can you post your thread that is dynamically added to the pool.

Comment: you want to the whole pool to be stop or just 1 runnable?

Comment: I want whole pool to be stopped

Comment: The pool itself is not doing anything. The Futures it creates are doing the job, so you have to stop them, not the pool. Just keep the reference on the Futures you create and then cancel them when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Keep your scheduled future for future reference.

```
final ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = scheduledThreadPool.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, INITIAL_DELAY,
            DELAY, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

To cancel, invoke cancel(boolean) method on your Future:

```
scheduledFuture.cancel(true);
```

You will have to keep all the Futures you will create from the pool to be able to cancel later.